How to find the parameters for the Lotka-Volterra model using a data set
For the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model:
dX/dt= aX-bXY,
dY/dt= cXY-dY.
Where X is the population of Hare and Y is the population of Lynx. I have a data set of both populations over a time period of 35 years.
I have functions for X(t), Y(t), X'(t), Y'(t). My original plan was to find the X,Y,dX/dt,dY/dt value for all time values and approximate a value for the parameters. However, this didn't yield mathematically correct results.
How can I estimate the parameters a,b,c,d in a mathematically correct way?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Only when hares and lynxes do us the favour to follow exactly that model. What makes us think that this is the case?

I cannot see the data (numerical) in the question. Also I cannot see what you dit and how you find incorrect results. How do you expect us to find where is the hitch ?

@CameronTytgat Very good catches !
